# Two UIPopovers in One View

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am trying to put two different UIPopovers in one view. I'm fairly new to objective-c, and programming in general, so instead of doing the smart, efficient method of having one popover and changing it's contents depending on how it is called, I just used the stupid, simple method of just creating two views, two delegates, two popovers etc... I don't know if that's why I'm having a problem, or if it's for some other reason.

So here's the problem. In the `viewdidload` of the view where the popovers appear, I have this code:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    optionsViewController =[[OptionsViewController alloc]init];
    optionsViewController.delegate = self;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:optionsViewController];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    [popoverController setDelegate:self];

    newCurrencyViewController =[[newCurrencyViewController alloc]init];
    newCurrencyViewController.delegate = self;
    newCurrencyPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newCurrencyViewController];
    newCurrencyPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    [newCurrencyPopoverController setDelegate:self];


}
```

Obviously `optionsViewController` is the vc that appears inside popover 1 (with popover controller called "popoverController"), and `newCurrencyViewController` is the vc that appears inside popover 2 (with popover controller called "`newCurrencyPopoverController`").

Every time the view loads, the app crashes with a `SIGABRT` error, and the console says:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:] must not be called with `nil`.'
```

Also, there's a warning saying "instance method -alloc not found (return type defaults to id)" for the line that

`saysnewCurrencyViewController =[[newCurrencyViewController alloc]init];`

My first thought was that I had misspelled the name of a file somewhere, since I think the problem is that it isn't finding the file called newCurrencyPopoverController, but I've checked everything and can't find any misspellings or anything. Any ideas?

Thanks very much!

LUKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling methods `alloc` + `init` of your variable `newCurrencyViewController` but you should call them to the class of that variable!

Line with bug:

```
newCurrencyViewController =[[newCurrencyViewController alloc]init];
```

The result of this line will be `newCurrencyViewController == nil`. And when you will try to init `UIPopoverController` with that view it will crash as you described.

If variable `newCurrencyViewController` is of class, for example, `CurrencyViewController` then you should replace that line with this one:

```
newCurrencyViewController =[[CurrencyViewController alloc] init];
```

Comment: Good explanation of the mistake. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

you dont have an object to call alloc and init on when you are calling newCurrenceViewController.

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

    optionsViewController =[[OptionsViewController alloc]init];
    optionsViewController.delegate = self;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:optionsViewController];
    popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    [popoverController setDelegate:self];

    //Here is your problem---------------------------------------------
    newCurrencyViewController =[[newCurrencyViewController alloc]init];
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    newCurrencyViewController.delegate = self;
    newCurrencyPopoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:newCurrencyViewController];
    newCurrencyPopoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 216);
    [newCurrencyPopoverController setDelegate:self];


}
```

you probably want something more like

```
newCurrencyViewController = [[UICurrencyViewController alloc] init];
```

Or w/e the name of your custom view controller is

Comment: Thanks so much. Only gave it to the guy above you because he was first, but thanks anyway. +1

Comment: @Nekto: Umm, when I made my post, yours was far from useful. You edited it while I made my post, and you even have the accepted answer. Not sure what you're complaining about.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the entire post I put before putting "yours is not right". UICurrencyViewController is a placeholder for the class the original poster actually needs. Its equivalent to your CurrencyViewController. My post explains that.